# final keyword in d and string return type issue

Tags: string, interface, d, final

I have got a quick question on what concerns some parts of D. First of all, can someone explain me the final keyword? I searched through the [dlang](http://dlang.org/) docs and it was just mentioned, not explained. And 2nd, in some tests, I am trying to do with interfaces (well, the problem is from a function return type). I get this [issue](http://prntscr.com/g22tza) .I don't get any problems form the ide, but it cant compile with this kind of warnings. I saw that that's the way to add variables to a string. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Regarding the issue... Your function is supposed to return a string, not a tuple. `return "something", value` will not work.

Answer (score 1):

D treats methods in classes as being virtual by default. final tells the compiler that subclasses will not be able to override the given function and then can make optimisations.

for your other question

```
import std.conv : to;

return "var is " ~ to!string(var);
```

~ is the append operator in d, 
to is the standard d function for converting one type to another, 
! denotes a compile time parameter

in case those things are new to you.

Comment: thank you very much, yes these things are new to me, especially d lang :) again, thank you